# Скролл вверх по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Посмотрите пожалуйста пример, внизу страницы input[file] кастомный, почему по клику на него, кидает вверх страницы ?

[Пример](https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/RjyzwL)

```js
document.querySelector("html").classList.add('js');

    var fileInput = document.querySelector(".input-file"),
      button = document.querySelector(".input-file-trigger"),
      the_return = document.querySelector(".file-return");

    button.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 32) {
        fileInput.focus();
      }
    });
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      fileInput.focus();
      return false;
    });
    fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      the_return.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
```

```css
.input-file-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 225px;
      padding-top: 500px;
    }

    .js .input-file-trigger {
      display: block;
      padding: 14px 45px;
      background: #39D2B4;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 1em;
      transition: all .4s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .js .input-file {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 225px;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 14px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .js .input-file:hover+.input-file-trigger,
    .js .input-file:focus+.input-file-trigger,
    .js .input-file-trigger:hover,
    .js .input-file-trigger:focus {
      background: #34495E;
      color: #39D2B4;
    }

    .file-return {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .file-return:not(:empty) {
      margin: 1em 0;
    }

    .js .file-return {
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: .9em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .js .file-return:not(:empty):before {
      content: "Selected file: ";
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
    }


    /* Useless styles, just for demo styles */

    body {
      font-family: "Open sans", "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #7F8C9A;
      background: #FCFDFD;
    }

    h1,
    h2 {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
      color: #aaa;
    }

    h2 {
      margin: 5px 0 2em;
      color: #1ABC9C;
    }

    form {
      width: 225px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h2+P {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .txtcenter {
      margin-top: 4em;
      font-size: .9em;
      text-align: center;
      color: #aaa;
    }

    .copy {
      margin-top: 2em;
    }

    .copy a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #1ABC9C;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Flat UI - Custom Input:file</h1>
    <h2>With JS return</h2>

    <form action="">
      <div class="input-file-container">
        <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
        <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
      </div>
      <p class="file-return"></p>
    </form>

    <p class="txtcenter">It's just a test, not really usable.<br />Works on IE &gt; 8 and modern browsers</p>
    <p class="txtcenter copy">by <a href="https://twitter.com/geoffrey_crofte">@geoffrey_crofte</a><br />see also <a href="https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/uEHeD">Custom input:file with CSS only</a></p>
```

Comment: допишите `event.preventDefault();` вероятно поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том что после вы даете фокус инпуту. а он в верху страницы.
В `css` снимаем как мне кажется лишний `top: 0;` и больше не кидает вверх. 
Оно написано для этого селектора `.js .input-file`

```js
document.querySelector("html").classList.add('js');

    var fileInput = document.querySelector(".input-file"),
      button = document.querySelector(".input-file-trigger"),
      the_return = document.querySelector(".file-return");

    button.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 32) {
        fileInput.focus();
      }
    });
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      fileInput.focus();
      return false;
    });
    fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      the_return.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
```

```css
.input-file-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 225px;
      padding-top: 500px;
    }

    .js .input-file-trigger {
      display: block;
      padding: 14px 45px;
      background: #39D2B4;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 1em;
      transition: all .4s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .js .input-file {
      position: absolute;
      //top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 225px;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 14px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .js .input-file:hover+.input-file-trigger,
    .js .input-file:focus+.input-file-trigger,
    .js .input-file-trigger:hover,
    .js .input-file-trigger:focus {
      background: #34495E;
      color: #39D2B4;
    }

    .file-return {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .file-return:not(:empty) {
      margin: 1em 0;
    }

    .js .file-return {
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: .9em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .js .file-return:not(:empty):before {
      content: "Selected file: ";
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
    }


    /* Useless styles, just for demo styles */

    body {
      font-family: "Open sans", "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #7F8C9A;
      background: #FCFDFD;
    }

    h1,
    h2 {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
      color: #aaa;
    }

    h2 {
      margin: 5px 0 2em;
      color: #1ABC9C;
    }

    form {
      width: 225px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h2+P {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .txtcenter {
      margin-top: 4em;
      font-size: .9em;
      text-align: center;
      color: #aaa;
    }

    .copy {
      margin-top: 2em;
    }

    .copy a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #1ABC9C;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Flat UI - Custom Input:file</h1>
<h2>With JS return</h2>

<form action="">
  <div class="input-file-container">
    <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
    <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
  </div>
  <p class="file-return"></p>
</form>

<p class="txtcenter">It's just a test, not really usable.<br />Works on IE &gt; 8 and modern browsers</p>
<p class="txtcenter copy">by <a href="https://twitter.com/geoffrey_crofte">@geoffrey_crofte</a><br />see also <a href="https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/uEHeD">Custom input:file with CSS only</a></p>
```